# How to a function right after a useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In class components, I was able to do something like this:

```js
this.setState({loading: true}, () => console.log('state updated'));
```

What is the equivalent in functional components using useState?

Comment: You can `useEffect` with `loading` as deps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the right way to do it is using the useEffect hook as mentioned before, and then passing as a parameter the state that we are listening to (in this case the count)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function onCountChange(){
    console.log('count has changed to', count);
  }
  // this will run every time count changes,
  useEffect(() => {
    // function that we want to run on ever change of count
    onCountChange()
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have additional logic you want to execute *after* your state has been set, that usually gets wrapped in a handler function specific to the action that is being performed:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Component = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const handleLoading = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    console.log('state updated');
  }

   return <button onClick={handleLoading}>Click Me</button>;
}
```

NOTE: As @Federkun notes below, this will not give you the state you just set because the component has not re-rendered yet.

Comment: This is how i would implement it too)

Comment: That's not wrong, but when `state updated` happen the component have not been re-rendered with the new state yet, which is not the equivalent of the old `setState`

Comment: @Federkun I wasn't sure if that is what they were asking, they could use `useEffect` to capture the last state change if so. However, if they only need to know if the state changed I think this approach is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you may benefit form useEffect hook for this purpose. Below, you can find an example from [the official React manual.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: count is a dependency of the useEffect: `useEffect(fun,[count])`